# why google candlestick chart looks ugly

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create candlestick chart using Google Chart API. However, the chart looks ugly no matter how i tweak the options. am i missing sth?

```
if (data != null){
            var d = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            d.addColumn("date", "day");
            d.addColumn("number", "low");
            d.addColumn("number", "open");
            d.addColumn("number", "close");
            d.addColumn("number", "high");
            for(i=data.Time.length-100; i < data.Time.length; i++){
                var date = new Date(data.Time[i].Year, data.Time[i].Month, data.Time[i].Day);
                d.addRow([date, data.Low[i], data.Open[i], data.Close[i], data.High[i]]);
            }

        var options = {
            legend: 'none',
            width: 1200,
            height: 600,
            bar: {groupWidth: '100%'},
            candlestick: {
                hollowIsRising: true,
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('divCharts'));
        chart.draw(d, options);
```

}

[image]

However the chart does looks as expected if i just use the example provided by google and use the same option:

```
d = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                                         ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
                                                         ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
                                                         ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
                                                         ['Thu', 50, 77, 66, 77],
                                                         ['Fri', 15, 66, 22, 68]], true); // Treat first row as data as well.
```

[image]

Comment: maybe too much data for the chart? could you add a range slider to narrow the axis?

Comment: that is a good idea. however i am still learning how can i make one. do you have example?

Comment: you'll need to incorporate a dashboard, as in the [google example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#googlevisualizationchartrangefilter) -- you might also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045241/google-chart-timeline-participants-failed-to-draw/33045763#33045763) if you encounter any errors